# python3.8 load dll OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, ctypes, dllimport, loadlibrary, oserror

env: windows10-64, python3.8.8,

CALL relation is -->

[image: relations]

1. in file `jgtrade_api_func_def.py`

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    #  coding:utf-8
    from ctypes import *
```

```
    
    jgtradeapi = windll.LoadLibrary('lib/td/JGTradeApi.dll')
```

2. in file `td_api.py`

```
    # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
    from jg_api.jgtrade_api import *
    ###
```

- in `main.py`

```
    from jg_api.td_api import JGTradeApi
```

- When I run `td_api.py`, it works well
- When I run `main.py`, FileNotFoundError

  File "D:\work\WCJGClient\jg_api\jgtrade_api_func_def.py", line 14, in 
  jgtradeapi = windll.LoadLibrary('lib/td/JGTradeApi.dll')
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 459, in LoadLibrary
  return self.*dlltype(name)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_*init**.py", line 381, in **init**
  self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
  FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'D:\work\WCJGClient\lib\td\JGTradeApi.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
- Then I change path as `windll.LoadLibrary('jg_api/lib/td/JGTradeApi.dll')`, the error changed

  File "D:\work\WCJGClient\jg_api\jgtrade_api_func_def.py", line 14, in 
  jgtradeapi = windll.LoadLibrary('jg_api/lib/td/JGTradeApi.dll')
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 459, in LoadLibrary
  return self.*dlltype(name)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_*init**.py", line 381, in **init**
  self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
  OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found.
- I also tried to use an absolute path, but reported the same error, Has anyone ever had such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I solved the problem！！！The reason is that the reference of DLL conflicts with pyside2！And when I change the import order, it works well
[image]